# Styling children of a modified component

Tags: css, bem

My team and I have started implementing something like BEM-ish (we used [this article](https://medium.com/@fat/mediums-css-is-actually-pretty-fucking-good-b8e2a6c78b06) as our starting point). What I've read so far seems to make sense. One big problem I'm wrapping my head around is how to style children of modified components.

For example, say I have `.avatar` and `.avatar--alternate` components/modifiers. Perhaps the background on alternate is black instead of white. What's CSS selectors should I use to style the headings in the alternate and why?

I've laid out the scenarios here:

```
<div class="avatar">
  <h2 class="avatar-heading">Lorem ipsum...</h2>
</div>

<div class="avatar avatar--dark">
  <h2 class="avatar-heading">Lorem ipsum...</h2>
</div>

// _typography.scss
h1 {
  color: #000;
}

// _avatar.scss
.avatar {
  background: #fff;
}
.avatar--dark {
  background: #000;
}
.avatar-heading {
  color: #222;
}


// option A
.avatar--dark {
  .avatar-heading {
    color: #fff;
  }
}

// option B
.avatar-heading--dark {
  color: #fff;
}

// option C?
```

My gut is telling me B because I this is the least specific way to style the heading and seems to be the most "scalable" or "future-proof". On the other hand, A is pretty compelling because I might potentially have `.avatar-subHeading` as well, and maybe some paragraphs in which case I might start suffering from classitis (?) (e.g. `<h1 class="avatar-heading avatar-heading--dark">`)

Answer (score 1):

Option C:

```
.avatar--dark > .avatar-heading {
    color: #fff;
}
```

All these options are correct.

Prefer C if `.avatar-heading` is always a child of `.avatar--dark` in the DOM tree.

Prefer A when you are sure that the component will never be recursively included inside itself.

Use B otherwise.

---

NB: In the BEM methodology, the second `div` should have both the component class `avatar` and the modifier class `avatar--dark`:

```
<div class="avatar avatar--dark">
```

Comment: Ahh yes, C makes sense (I'm looking at you, dropdown navigations). I'll mark as the answer if nothing better comes in. Thanks!